# Using variable values in LOAD * INLINE Statement

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I am trying to use variable values within a load inline statement but rather than the variable values being loaded im getting a weird substring of the variable formula.

What i am doing wrong?

So TEMPTABLE is loaded from a file, its shows monthly data, i need to show that data as daily data, so i divide the values by the number of days in that month and then want to load these into 'Final' table.

```
Set vNoOfRows = NoOfRows('TEMPTABLE');

FOR i=0 to $(vNoOfRows)
  SET vYear=Peek('Year',$(i),'TEMPTABLE');
  SET vMonthName=Peek('MonthName',$(i),'TEMPTABLE');    
  SET vCOMPANYNAME=Peek('COMPANYNAME',$(i),'TEMPTABLE'); 
  SET vTYPE_BUSINESS=Peek('TYPE_BUSINESS',$(i),'TEMPTABLE'); 
  SET vSUB_PRODUCT=Peek('SUB_PRODUCT',$(i),'TEMPTABLE'); 
  SET vRENEWAL=Peek('RENEWAL',$(i),'TEMPTABLE'); 
  SET vDaysincurrentmonth=Peek('DaysInMonth',$(i),'TEMPTABLE');
  SET vDayCount=Peek('Daycount',$(i),'TEMPTABLE');  
  SET vPolicies_Day=Peek('Policies_Day',$(i),'TEMPTABLE');
  SET vUWP_Day=Peek('UWP_Day',$(i),'TEMPTABLE');
  SET vGWP_IPT_Day=Peek('GWP-IPT_Day',$(i),'TEMPTABLE');
  SET vClaims_Day=Peek('Claims_Day',$(i),'TEMPTABLE');
  SET vIncurred_Day=Peek('Incurred_Day',$(i),'TEMPTABLE');  

  Set a=1;

   Do while a<=$(vDaysincurrentmonth)       

    FINAL:
    LOAD * INLINE [
            Year,MonthName,Day,COMPANYNAME,TYPE_BUSINESS,SUB_PRODUCT,RENEWAL,Policies_Day,UWP_Day,GWP_IPT_Day,Claims_Day,Incurred_Day
            =$(vYear),=$(vMonthName),=$(a),=$(vCOMPANYNAME),=$(vTYPE_BUSINESS),=$(vSUB_PRODUCT),=$(vRENEWAL),=$(vPolicies_Day),=$(vUWP_Day),=$(vGWP_IPT_Day),=$(vClaims_Day),=$(vIncurred_Day)     
     ];

    Let a=$(a)+1;
  Loop

NEXT i
DROP TABLE TEMPTABLE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables in script behave differently than they do on the expression side. In the script they are more like "replace this variable by the current value" than an actual variable evaluation.

That said, don't use the equal signs (not needed) and make sure that all variables that are not numeric are enclosed in '. For instance :

```
$(vYear),'$(vMonthName)',$(a),'$(vCOMPANYNAME)'
```

This should get you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks but im still really stuck. if i wrap `$(vYear)` in quote the value that gets loaded in is: `Peek('Year',$(i),'TEMPTABLE'). If i remove the quotes all that gets loaded is: `Peek('Year`, how do i get it to load the actual assigned value rather than a sting of the expression?

Comment: I had already tried that, it doesnt make any difference. Any other ideas?

Comment: Using this code : Set vNoOfRows = NoOfRows('MyTable');
TRACE With SET = $(vNoOfRows);
Let vNoOfRows = NoOfRows('MyTable');
TRACE With LET = $(vNoOfRows); I get the following output : "With SET = NoOfRows('MyTable') / With LET = 2". LET and SET do have a differente behaviour. Use the TRACE command to help you debug.

Comment: Sorry i thought you meant just change the vNoOfRows Set to Let, i changed all the sets to lets and its working perfectly! thanks for your help